# ggplot2 requiring explicit mention of mapping argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried this formula which used to work

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot()+
  geom_point(iris,aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

But I get the following error:
Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

When I rerun the code with the mapping argument mentioned explicitly, it works:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(iris,mapping=aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

I tried reloading RStudio, but still not working... not sure what happened here.

Comment: I'm sure that code never used to work. ggplot has never used that order for parameters. It's more common to have code that looks like `ggplot(iris)+geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))` so maybe what's what worked before. If you are using unnamed parameters, you need to make sure the order matches the function signature to get things to match up.

Comment: Didnt realize that order of arguments are different b/w ggplot() and geom_point()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that in `geom_point`, the first argument is `mapping` and second is `data`.  As per the `Usage` in documentation of `?geom_point`

> geom_point(
> mapping = NULL,
> data = NULL,
> stat = "identity",
> position = "identity",
> ...,
> na.rm = FALSE,
> show.legend = NA,
> inherit.aes = TRUE
> )

So, if we don't specify the arguments, it thinks the first argument which is given as `iris` as `mapping`

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

To build a ggplot we use the basic template:

```
ggplot(data = <DATA>, mapping = aes(<MAPPINGS>)) +  <GEOM_FUNCTION>()
```

This code:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()
```

is the same with this:

```
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks...but that way doesnt allow you to use  different datasets for different geoms. Will be accepting Akruns answer